# SSRS Report to show 2014 and 2015 revenue values from 1 datasource

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create an ssrs report that displays a company and its 2014 revenue and its 2015 revenue. The data itself exists in a single datasource. I am trying to do this using 1 dataset and a tablix.  Is there an easy way to do this or am I going to need to create multiple datasets and use a lookup function to create the necessary output?

Example of what I need the output to be is below.

Company Name | 2015 Revenue | 2014 Revenue

Comment: I think it may require only one dataset but It depends of the way the data is stored in your datasource. Provide a sample of the underlying table in order to help you.

Comment: OK so the data itself is stored in a table with columns for Company ID, Charge, Delivery Year

Comment: How is the revenue calculated from that data? Or Charge column contains revenue value?

Comment: The charge value is the revenue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the table you exposed in comments, I've recreated it with sample data. Then I've used the [PIVOT()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function to pivot the data as your requeriment.

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT
  'Company A' Company,
  1000 [Charge],
  2014 DeliveryYear
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Company A',
  750,
  2015
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Company B',
  600,
  2014
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Company B',
  800,
  2015)
SELECT
  *
FROM CTE
PIVOT (SUM(Charge) FOR DeliveryYear IN ([2014], [2015])) AS Revenue
```

Try it yourself: <kbd>**[`Example button`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422754/sample-data)**</kbd>

Use that query in SSRS dataset. Now just add a tablix and set this data arrangement.

[image]

It produces the following preview:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.